# Files not added to ZIP

Tags: php, ftp

Am developing a code that creates a ZIP file out of selected files from a folder. The folder is created with sessiontime as name, but the files are not added to the ZIP file. The permissions of files are 777. The files are getting selected, indicated by the output below. I have also checked the code by replacing with line $zip->addFile($file_folder); which downloads a blank zip archive, hence there is no issue with it.

```
<?php
ob_start();
$error = "";        //error holder
if(isset($_POST['createpdf']))
{
    $post = $_POST;     
    $file_folder = "test/".$_SESSION["dir_name"]."/";   // folder to load files
    echo $file_folder;
    if(extension_loaded('zip'))

    {   // Checking ZIP extension is available
        echo "checking";
        if(isset($post['files']) and count($post['files']) > 0)
        {   echo "/checking2";// Checking files are selected
            $zip = new ZipArchive();            // Load zip library 
            $zip_name = time().".zip";          // Zip name

            if($zip->open($zip_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE)
            {   
                // Opening zip file to load files
                echo "* Sorry ZIP creation failed at this time<br/>";
            }
            foreach($post['files'] as $file)
            {   echo "added";           
                $zip->addFile($file_folder.$file);          // Adding files 
into zip
            }
            $zip->close();
            if(file_exists($zip_name))
            {
                // push to download the zip
                header('Content-type: application/zip');
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$zip_name.'"');
                readfile($zip_name);
                // remove zip file is exists in temp path
                unlink($zip_name);
```

The output I get is the line : test//checking/checking2addedaddedadded

Comment: What is output of code? Is there any info "added"?  Are you sure that files exist in $file_folder ?

Comment: Have you checked over file_exists if your path+filename is correct? Please try to check this first, since it could be a path problem with relative paths.

Comment: Edited the question statement, with the output

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `session_start()` after opening the `<?php` tag, so your `$_SESSION['dir_name']` variable is empty

Comment: The files are uploaded on the server already by a script that runs prior to redirection of control to this php page.

Comment: I had that in the code, but had removed it later after adding ob_start() function. The output I get with session function is:      test/1399965744/checking/checking2addedadded

Comment: It still not working? You have to assure that the files were successfully uploaded in `test/1399965744/` before adding them in the zip archive

Comment: Yes its still not working. The files are present on the server, no doubts in that.